# detecting for off bounded squares on grid

Tags: javascript

I'm going through a tutorial, and apparently I'm suppose to be getting this. But I can't find wrong in the coding part, I'm going step by step as well. I'm geting nothing, but before I had a block falling from above. Apparently I'm suppose to be getting something like 
[image: what i'm suppose to be geting at]

```
var WIDTH = 300,
    HEIGHT = 400,
    c = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    ctx = c.getContext('2d');

setInterval(function() {
    clearCanvas();
    generateNextSquare();
    updatePosition();
    drawOnCanvas();
}, 1000 / 50);

var clearCanvas = function() {
    ctx.fillStyle = 'White';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
}

var drawLine = function() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(200, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(200, 400);
    ctx.stroke();
}

var updatePosition = function() {
    _square.fall();
}

var drawOnCanvas = function() {
    drawLine();
    _square.draw();
}
var squareLength = 20;
var speedLevels = [20, 16, 12, 10, 8],
    currSpeed = speedLevels[0];

var gameGrid = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
];


var Square = function(speed) {
    var self = this;
    self.color = "Black";
    self.vPosition = 0;
    self.hPosition = 4;
    self.speed = speed;
    self.current = 0 ;
    self.temp = 0;

    self.fall = function() {
        if (self.counter >= self.speed) {
            if (self.checkFalling()) {
                self.vPosition++;
            } else {
                gameGrid[self.vPosition][self.hPosition] = 1;
                self.active = false;
            }
            self.counter = 0;
        }
        self.counter++;
    }
    self.checkFalling = function() {
        if (gameGrid[self.vPosition + 1][self.hPosition] == 1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
}
return self;
}


var drawFixedSquares = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            if (gameGrid[i][j] == 1) {
                ctx.fillStyle = "Black";
                ctx.fillRect(j * squareLength, i * squareLength, squareLength, squareLength);
            }
        }
    }
}
var generateNextSquare = function() {
    if (!_square.active)
        _square = new Square(currSpeed);
}
var _square = new Square(currSpeed);
```

Comment: Too many errors in that code...

Comment: The code that you had given is not proper. For example  `return self;
}` at the end of `Square` class is just floating outside. In `drawOnCanvas` function we are invoking `_squre.draw()` but there is no method `draw` in the class `Square`. Check these and provide a proper code to debug.